# Is there a method in R of extracting nested relational data tables from a JSON file?

Tags: r, json, dataframe, parsing

I am currently researching publicly available payer transparency files across multiple insurers and I am trying to parse and extract JSON files using R and output them into .CSV files to later use with SQL. The file I am currently working with contains nested tables within the highest table.

I have attached the specific file I am working with right now in a link below, along with the code to mount it into R's dataviewer. I have used R extensively in healthcare analytics classes for statistical analysis and machine learning; though, I have never used R for building out data tables.

My goal is to assign a primary key to the highest level of the table, apply foreign and primary keys to lower tables and extract the lower tables and join them onto eachother later to build out a large CSV or TXT file to load onto SQL.

So far, I have used the jsonlite and rjson packages to extract the JSON itself into R, but trying to delist an unnest the tables within the tables are an enigma to me even after extensive research. I also find myself running into problems with "subscript out of bounds", "unimplemented list errors" and other issues.

It could also very well be the case that the JSON is too large for R's packages or that the JSON is structurally flawed (I wouldn't know if it is, I am not accustomed to JSONs). It seems that this could be a problem better solved with Python, though I don't know how to use Python too well and I am optimistic in R given how powerful it is.

Any feedback or answers would be greatly appreciated.

JSON file link: https://individual.carefirst.com/carefirst-resources/machine-readable/Provider_Med_5.json

Code to load JSON:

```
json2 <- fromJSON('https://individual.carefirst.com/carefirst-resources/machine-readable/Provider_Med_5.json')
```

1. JSONs load correctly, but there are tables embedded within tables. I would hope that these tables could be easily exported and have keys for joining, but I can not figure out how to denest these tables from within the data.
2. Some nested tables are out of subscript bounds for the data array. I have never encountered this problem and am bewildered as to how to go about and resolve the issue.
3. I can not figure out how to 'extract' the lower level tables, let alone open them, due to the subscript boundary error.
4. I can assign row ID to the main/highest table in the file, but I can not figure out how to add sub row ID's to the lower table for future joins.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [**jsonStrings**](https://github.com/stla/jsonStrings) package can help. It allows to manipulate JSON, without converting to a R object. That's the first time I try it on such a big JSON string and it works fine.

Here is how to get the table in the first element of the JSON array:

```r
options(timeout = 300)
download.file(
  "https://individual.carefirst.com/carefirst-resources/machine-readable/Provider_Med_5.json",
  "jsonFile.json"
)

library(jsonStrings)
# load the JSON file
jstring <- jsonString$new("jsonFile.json")
# extract table "plans" of first element (indexed by 0)
jsonTable <- jstring$at(0, "plans")

# get a dataframe
library(jsonlite)
dat <- fromJSON(jsonTable$asString())
```

But the dataframe `dat` has a list column. I don't know how you want to make a CSV with this dataframe.